# What is the maximum length of a circuit in the complete graph on n vertices.

Tags: graph-theory

A trail is a sequence of adjacent vertices with no repeated edges.  A circuit is a trail that begins and ends at the same vertex.  The complete graph on 3 vertices has a circuit of length 3.  The complete graph on 4 vertices has a circuit of length 4.  the complete graph on 5 vertices has a circuit of length 10.

How can I find the maximum circuit length for the complete graph on n vertices?

Comment: If $n$ is odd the maximum circuit length is exactly $n*(n-1)/2$.

Comment: Yep this is a consequence of the famous "bridges of konigsberg" problem.

You can also google "eulerian circuit".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is highly related to [Eulerian Circuits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path).

Definition: An Eulerian circuit is a circuit which uses every edge in the graph.

By a theorem of Euler, there exists an Eulerian circuit if and only if each vertex has even degree. Hence, the maximum circuit length for $n$ vertices is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ when $n$ is odd (the total number of edges), and $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-\frac{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-2)}{2}$ when $n$ is even (we can just delete one edge for each two vertices to make the degree of every vertex even).