# How can I find the longest simple circuit in $K_n$?

Tags: graph-theory

How can I find the longest simple circuit in $K_n$? Is there a simple formula that exists?

Comment: Do mean you the circuit of length $n$?

Comment: @Salomo. No, I mean the longest simple circuit. It doesn't have to be of length $n$.

Comment: But it seems it has to be of length $n$.

Comment: A cycle (simple circuit) can visit the nodes of $K_n$ in any order you wish.

Comment: @Salomo That is not true. You can easily show that it is not so.

Comment: @Julia : You should provide your definition of a simple circuit.

Comment: @ManuelLafond: A simple path that begins and ends at the same vertex. A simple path is a path between two vertices without including the same edge more than once.

Comment: Then check this out : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807110/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-circuit-in-the-complete-graph-on-n-vertices